# Number of solutions.

Tags: calculus

> For each positive real number $\lambda$, let $A_\lambda$ be the set of all natural numbers $n$ such that $|\sin\sqrt{n+1}-\sin\sqrt n|<\lambda$. Let $A_\lambda^c$ be the complement of $A_\lambda$ in the set of all natural numbers. Then
>   (A) $A_{1/2},A_{1/3},A_{2/5}$ are all finite sets
>   (B) $A_{1/3}$ is a finite set but $A_{1/2},A_{2/5}$ are infinite sets
>   (C) $A_{1/2}^c,A_{1/3}^c,A_{2/5}^c$ are all finite sets
>   (D) $A_{1/3},A_{2/5}$ are finite sets and $A_{1/2}$ is an infinite set

How to actually start the problem? I tried using finding monotonocity of the function by replacing $n$ by $x$. But am not able to comment.

At infinity the limit is 0. How to use that.

Comment: How is the sine monotone? And what limit do you mean?

Comment: replacing n by x in the difference inside mod , i took the whole difference as a function of x. the limit to infinity to that difference is 0 .

Comment: Ok, that part is definitely true. But the function is not monotone

Comment: All $A_\lambda$ is infinite set as $|\sin(\sqrt{n+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{n})| \stackrel{\text{MVT}}{\le} \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin \sqrt{n+1} - \sin \sqrt{n}=2 \sin \frac12 (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) \cos \frac12 (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})= \\ = 2 \sin \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} \cos \frac12 (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})$$

From this we can see that the limit for $n \to \infty$ is really $0$, as the OP claims.

Now we need to show that there's an infinite set of $n$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that:

$$2 \left|\sin \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} \cos \frac12 (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}) \right| < \lambda$$

This actually directly follows from the definition of the limit at $\infty$ and our claim that it's $0$. But let's consider it more carefully:

We have:

$$2 \left|\sin \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} \cos \frac12 (\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}) \right| < \\ < 2 \left|\sin \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Now pick:

$$N = \begin{cases} 1, & \lambda > \frac12 \\  \frac{1}{4 \lambda^2}, & \lambda \leq \frac12 \end{cases}$$

For any $n>N$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} < \lambda$$

$$|\sin \sqrt{n+1} - \sin \sqrt{n}| < \lambda$$

Since there's an infinite set of $n$ larger than some finite $N$, we have proven that for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$ the set $A_\lambda$ is infinite.

---

Conversely, we also need to prove that the complement of this set is finite.

Consider:

$$|\sin \sqrt{n+1} - \sin \sqrt{n}| \geq \lambda$$

We have already proved that for any $n>N$ defined as above, the opposite inequality holds. Which means, we are only left with the set of $n \leq N$ to pick from, which is finite by definition.

So we have proved that every complementary set is finite, which leaves the option (C).